# How can i find if a variable has a special character in it?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Im trying to find, in my javascript, if i can identify in a variable if a "@" sign is present in the variable.

```
 e = _("email").value;

 if(e don't contain "@"){
     alert("Dosnt contain @");
 }
 else {
     alert("email has @");
 }
```

Comment: have a look at [String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) / [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: if(yourstring.indexOf('@')){alert("Contains @");}

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expressions to validate an email. Would be more easy to maintain and manage.

```
$('form input[name="email"]').blur(function () {
    var email = $(this).val();
    var re = /[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/igm;
    if (re.test(email)) {
        $('.msg').hide();
        $('.success').show();
    } else {
    $('.msg').hide();
    $('.error').show();
    }
});
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/33acr/embedded/result/)

Comment: But, at the time i have to pass it to php, how the code would be?

Comment: @Soundbust you can pass the value of the textbox to php with a form submission.

Comment: Can the person who downvoted my answer at least have the courtesy of posting his/her answer or explaining why the downvote? It's quite obvious that the OP wants to validate email addresses and he is just checking for the @ sign... suggesting regular expressions is much better than custom javascript validation...